# Content inside div not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this hidden div and when i click a button it shows right
but when i try to put a `<p>` inside the div it wont show, only if I take out `<p>`
everything is good but i only want to put style to the paragraph like `<br>` and other stuff to make it look better.  please take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/baJme/1/)

html

`<section>
    <a rel="external" href="#button" id="button" class="button">&#xF011;
    </a>
    <span></span>
    </section>`

jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('on');
$('p').toggleClass('hidn');
    $('div[id=container]').toggleClass('container');
    $('p[id=p1]').toggleClass('p1');
});
});
```

Comment: instead of `div[id=container]` use the id selector `#container`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're toggling the class `hidn` on all the paragraph tags, Instead add an unique `id` to  specific `<p>` tag.Try this:

**Html:**

```
<p id="p0" class="hidn" style="font-size: 50px;font-family: Razer Header Regular;
top: 20%; color: rgb(192,192,192); position: relative; text-align: center;">
```

**Jquery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#button').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass('on');
    $('#p0').toggleClass('hidn');
    $('#container').toggleClass('container');
    $('#p1').toggleClass('p1');
});
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/baJme/2/)

Comment: this is good but, however since i have another text that whevener i click the button goes away, with this code it stays, it wont hide

Comment: You want to hide the button which is being clicked??

Comment: no there is another txt that whenever i click the button it hides

Answer (score 0):

You're toggling the class `hidn` on all the paragraph tags, including the ones inside your div.  But since the ones in the div don't have the class, it's getting added on, making them invisible.

Edit: So either make that paragraph toggle more targeted, or set a rule to make pargraphs with the `hidn` class in your content div not be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

Add the 'hidn' class to the problematic paragraph since you're toggling it as well due to bad jQuery selectors.

http://jsfiddle.net/baJme/4/

```
<p id="p1" class="p1 hidn">
```

However, I'd strongly suggest rewriting the code with proper selectors. Also, follow Arun's advice from the comments about selecting ids.